npm install error: "could not solve dependency" but references packages that are not on the project
when I run npm install, I get errors like:
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^15.2.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from @coreui/angular@2.17.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@coreui/angular
npm ERR!   @coreui/angular@"^2.15.0" from the root project

OR
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^15.2.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=16.0.3" from ngx-csv-parser@1.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-csv-parser
npm ERR!   ngx-csv-parser@"^1.2.0" from the root project

but the versions I have on my packages.json file are:
"@angular/common": "^15.2.10",
"@coreui/angular": "^2.15.0",
"ngx-csv-parser": "^1.2.0",
instead of the ones mentioned in the error message:
@angular/common@17.0.0
@coreui/angular@2.17.0
ngx-csv-parser@1.3.1
@angular/common@16.0.3
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/common": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/compiler": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/forms": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/router": "^15.2.10",
"@codewithdan/observable-store": "^1.0.22",
"@coreui/angular": "^2.15.0",
"@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.12",
"@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
"@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
"@okta/okta-angular": "^3.1.0",
"@types/file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"ag-grid-angular": "^22.0.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^22.0.0",
"angular2-query-builder": "0.5.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"chart.js": "^2.8.0",
"ckeditor4-angular": "^1.3.0",
"core-js": "^2.6.9",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"i18n-iso-countries": "^5.3.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"localforage": "^1.10.0",
"lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
"material-icons": "^0.3.1",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.26",
"mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
"ng-openapi-gen": "^0.17.2",
"ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
"ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
"ngforage": "^9.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
"ngx-csv-parser": "^1.2.0",
"ngx-device-detector": "^4.0.0",
"ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^15.2.2",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^16.0.0",
"ngx-ui-loader": "^13.0.0",
"popper.js": "^1.15.0",
"primeicons": "^5.0.0",
"primeng": "^14.0.1",
"quill": "^1.3.7",
"rxjs": "^6.6.7",
"simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.11",
"@angular/cli": "^15.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/language-service": "^15.2.10",
"@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "^8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "^4.9.5"
},


please share package.json dependencies and devDependencies

@NarenMurali question updated with requested info

but references packages that are not on the project As far as I can see, @coreui/angular, ngx-csv-parser and @angular/common are all part of the project.

@hikizume What happens when you try this command => npm i --legacy-peer-deps ?

@DavidR it installs fine but I'd like to avoid potentially introducing breaking changes

@JSONDerulo yes but different versions. Why am I getting an error referencing an issue with @coreui/angular@2.17.0 when I have 2.15.0 installed?

Because you have prefixed the version with ^ which means that new minor and patch versions will be automatically installed. As far as I can see, everything is working exactly as expected.

@JSONDerulo gotcha thanks for pointing that out
